# Esri MAP Showing ARE.StreetName instead of Actual street name or address.

Tags: javascript, esri

I am using ESRI Map geocodes method to retrieve addresses of particulars pointer. e.g if a person clicked on streets of map, there will be an info window open with these informations. Adress, city and Address. other informations retrieving perfectly but in streets section it is showing USA.PointAddress. i don't know why this ${Loc_name} is not showing proper street and even city is also showing location. look at fiddle for reference.

Any help regarding this issue will be appriciated.

```js
// Add Location MAP Code star from here //
        /* Esri Map GeoLocation */

        var map, gsvc, pt;
        var o;

        function getaddress() {
            $("#txtIncidentLongitude").val(o.location.x);
            $("#txtIncidentLatitude").val(o.location.y);
            $("#txtIncidentStreet").val(o.address.Loc_name);
            $("#txtIncidentArea").val(o.address.Neighborhood);
            $("#txtIncidentCity").val(o.address.City);
            $("#txtIncidentEmirate").val(o.address.Region);
        };
        require([
          "esri/map", "esri/tasks/locator", "esri/graphic", "esri/tasks/GeometryService", "esri/tasks/ProjectParameters", "esri/SpatialReference", "esri/InfoTemplate", "esri/dijit/Search", "esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol", "esri/Color", "dojo/number", "dojo/parser", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dijit/registry", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function (
          Map, Locator, Graphic, GeometryService, ProjectParameters, SpatialReference, InfoTemplate, Search, webMercatorUtils, SimpleMarkerSymbol, PictureMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, Color, number, parser, dom, on, registry) {
            parser.parse();
            map = new Map("map", {
                basemap: "streets",
                center: [-74.6851, 40.6884],
                zoom: 9
            });

            var locator = new Locator("https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer");
            gsvc = new GeometryService("https://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

            var search = new Search({
                map: map
            }, "search");
            $('#search_input').attr('placeholder', 'Find Address');

        search.startup();



        search.on("select-result", showLocation);
        function showLocation(e) {
            map.graphics.clear();
            var point = e.result.feature.geometry;
            var ppy = point.getLatitude().toFixed(4);
            var ppx = point.getLongitude().toFixed(4);
        };
        dojo.connect(map, "onClick", function (evt) {
            map.graphics.clear();
            var def = locator.locationToAddress(esri.geometry.webMercatorToGeographic(evt.mapPoint), 100);

            def.then(function (candidate) {

                if (candidate.address) {
                    o = candidate;

                    /*$("#txtIncidentStreet").val(o.address.Loc_name);
                    $("#txtIncidentArea").val(o.address.Neighborhood);
                    $("#txtIncidentCity").val(o.address.City);*/

                    var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Location", "<table width='100%' class='m-t'><tr><td>Address: </td><td>${Address}</td></tr><tr><td>City: </td><td>${City}</td></tr><tr><td>Street: </td><td>${Loc_name}</td></tr></table><p style='margin:0' class='text-center'><a class='btn m-t btn-sm btn-primary' onClick='getaddress();' id='addloc' href='javascript:;'><i class='fa fa-plus-square'></i> Add Location</a></p>");
                        var symbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol({
                            "url": 'dist/images/active.png',
                            "height": 27,
                            "width": 16,
                            "yoffset": 12,
                        });
                        // this service returns geocoding results in geographic - convert to web mercator to display on map  
                        var location = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(candidate.location);
                        var graphic = new esri.Graphic(location, symbol, candidate.address, infoTemplate);
                        map.graphics.add(graphic);

                        map.infoWindow.setTitle(graphic.getTitle());
                        map.infoWindow.setContent(graphic.getContent());

                        //display the info window with the address information
                        var screenPnt = map.toScreen(location);
                        map.infoWindow.resize(300, 250);
                        map.infoWindow.show(screenPnt, map.getInfoWindowAnchor(screenPnt));
                    } else {
                        //no address found  
                        console.log("No address found for this location");
                    }
                }, function (error) {

                    var latitude = evt.mapPoint.getLatitude();
                    var longitude = evt.mapPoint.getLongitude();
                    map.infoWindow.setTitle("Location");
                map.infoWindow.setContent(
                  "<strong>Address not Available</strong><br>" + "Latitude: " + latitude.toFixed(4) + "<br>Logitude: " + longitude.toFixed(4)
                          );
                map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint, map.getInfoWindowAnchor(evt.screenPoint));
                console.log("error: " + error.message);
            });
            });
    });
```

```css
        #map, .map.container {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #info {
            top: 2px;
            color: #444;
            height: auto;
            font-family: arial;
            font-weight: bold;
            left: 69px;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 260px;
            z-index: 40;
            border: solid 1px #003300;
            border-radius: 4px;
            background-color: #E5E5E5;
        }

        #search {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            top: 36px;
            left: 74px;
        }
        /*Beginning of search box modifications*/
        .arcgisSearch .searchClear {
            background-color: #E5E5E5;
        }

        .arcgisSearch .esriIconZoom {
            background-image: url("finding.png");
            background-size: 20px 20px;
        }

        .esriIconZoom:before {
            content: "";
        }

        .arcgisSearch .searchGroup .searchInput,
        .arcgisSearch .searchBtn,
        .arcgisSearch .noResultsMenu,
        .arcgisSearch .suggestionsMenu {
            border: 1px solid #003300;
            background-color: #E5E5E5;
        }

        .arcgisSearch .noValueText {
            color: red;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        /*Beginning of popup modifications*/
        .esriPopup .titlePane {
            background-color: #015a82;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #121310;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .esriPopup a {
            color: #DAE896;
        }
```

```html
<link href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.16/esri/css/esri.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.16/init.js"></script>
<div id="search"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```